# jQuery mobile: dialog page contains unwanted chars (?> or ?&gt;)

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-dialog

First of all, let me show you a bit of code:

index.php

```
<a href="new-directory-dialog.php" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slidedown"><?php echo localize('New directory'); ?></a>
```

So, as you can see, I use *new-directory-dialog.php* as a dialog window. All works fine on local machine, using Wamp server on Win 7 x64. But on my web host server, every dialog page is displayed with ?> (or ?&gt;) chars.
HTML tab in Firebug shows this output:

```
<html class="ui-mobile">
<head>
<base href="http://pantljika-online.info/link/new-directory-dialog.php">
</head>
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-a">
?>
<title>Novi direktorij</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
```

I have no clue why is this happening.
Here is entire code for dialog page:

```
<?php
include('localize.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo localize('New directory'); ?></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="<?php echo $_SESSION['data-theme']; ?>" >
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <div data-role="header">
                        <h1><?php echo localize('New directory'); ?></h1>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="content">
                        <label for="new-directory-name">
                            <?php echo localize('Name'); ?>:
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" id="new-directory-name" name="new-directory-name" />
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="footer">
                        <h4>
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit-value"><?php echo localize('Create'); ?></button>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Prevent the output of those strings on your webserver. Unless you don't do that, you will have it there (from your code alone you've pasted it can not be said what causes the output).

Comment: How can I do that? Also, I find it strange that content of head tag is in body tag when dialog is loaded.

Comment: You need to troubleshoot that. Find the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem solved. I deleted PHP closing tag (?>) in one of the included php files and it stopped showing up on dialogs. Also I had to encode all php files from UTF8 to UTF8 without BOM. Otherwise jQuery puts head metatags and title tag inside body element...